# how to make border in pattern bar-stacked still black

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I currently working on gnuplot bar-stacked with patterns. I have to create pattern with combination of colors, but I want to keep the border still black. how set it? As far as I know gnuplot doing

> lc rgb "#006600"  lt -1 fs pattern 1, \

and border color also use

> lc

.

this is my data:

```
CS  31.73   18.32   20.78   22.88   1.97    1.29    0.90    2.01
FL  43.27   29.45   15.64   6.55    1.64    1.27    2.18    0.00
HB  32.44   20.43   14.89   14.53   5.42    10.92   0.80    0.31
HD  28.53   7.27    29.53   20.33   9.18    0.93    2.04    1.44
MR  22.56   36.19   10.66   15.51   9.45    4.32    0.80    0.31
ZK  27.15   10.81   27.40   16.10   8.05    7.24    1.06    1.71
All 30.00   21.35   18.05   16.82   6.14    5.39    1.11    0.85
```

and this is my gnuplot file:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set key invert reverse above
set boxwidth 0.8
set format y "%.0f%%"
set border 3 
set yrange [0:100]
set size 0.9 , 1.8

set label 1 "1092" at -0.3,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 2 "500" at 0.7,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 3 "1000" at 1.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 4 "500" at 2.8,103  font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 5 "1000" at 3.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 6 "500" at 4.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 
set label 7 "500" at 5.8,103 font "Times-Roman, 17" 


set output 'aspect.eps'
plot 'a3b-aspect' \
    using($2):xtic(1)   t "pattern 1"  lc rgb "#006600"  lt -1 fs pattern 1, \
''  using($3)           t "pattern 2"  lc rgb "#006600"  lt -1 fs pattern 2, \
''  using($4)           t "pattern 3"  lc rgb "#330000"  lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($5)           t "pattern 4" lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 4, \
''  using($6)           t "pattern 5"  lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 5, \
''  using($7)           t "pattern 6"   lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 6, \
''  using($8)           t "pattern 7"  lc rgb "#000099"  lt -1 fs pattern 7, \
''  using($5)           t "pattern 3" lc rgb "#660000"  lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($6)           t "pattern 3"   lc rgb "#990000"  lt -1 fs pattern 3
```

and this is my output:
[image]

How to make the border colors is black for my all patterns? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
set style fill pattern border lt -1
```

[image]

Comment: Akhtar one more thing. why my graphs have space between y axis and the first bar? what's wrong with my way to plot?